# AngularJS Duplicate GET request

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I don't know why, but i have two duplicate request from my controller "AuditionCtrl" to database.
Please help understand this trouble.

here you can see two get request
[image]
  Github my project https://vonoprienko@bitbucket.org/vonoprienko/iknowit.git

Comment: your repo is private

Comment: sorry, wait one second. pls  https://bitbucket.org/vonoprienko/iknowit/overview

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate: [function called twice inside angularjs controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608978/function-called-twice-inside-angularjs-controller)

This is your audition.html

```
<div class="container-fluid fill" ng-controller="AuditionCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <p>Welcome to exercise listening and typing!</p>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="readbtn();">Play</button>
            <br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="userAnswer" placeholder="Type heard">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="nextWord();">Next word</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="skipWord();">Skip</button>
            <br>
            <label id="labelMessage" ng-bind="showCorrect"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is a portion of your app.js

```
.when('/audition', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/audition.html',
        controller: 'AuditionCtrl',
        access: {
          requiredLogin: false
        }
```

As mentioned in the answer. You have attached your controller to multiple elements which leads to Angular calling digest on the controller twice.

Comment: Thanks, very simple solution!